# can I use a file instead of server side "apache http server + PHP + MySQL"

Tags: php, ajax, apache

Hey, friend. as show in title:
My aim is "use ajax to connect with client side written with asp.net and server side written with whatever",  can I use a file instead of server side "apache http server + PHP + MySQL"?
Instead of server side tech composite, the Demo still need to show ajax's asynchronous power,
Is the design workable? thanks first:)

Comment: A file? for what? Breaking out of jail? Soothing off a rough edge?

Comment: Just for doing an AJAX demo, friend. This solution use a html page instead the complexity of deploying server-side techs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mis-understanding your question, yes, you can use a static file instead of a dynamically generated PHP/MySQL scenario...for instance, pulling in an XML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("SOMETAGNAME");
        //do something with it
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","staticfile.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I means, I also have a trial on html page as a virtual server, it also works :)